# Access denied - Map network drive to azure file share

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a file share on my azure account and I am trying to use the map network drive function inside of windows explorer to access the share. however, when I enter my credentials, it takes be back and says access denied inside of the credentials windows.

[image: Problem]

Please help!

Thanks

-Sean

Comment: Please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share (section `Mount the file share from an on-premises client running Windows`).

Comment: I solved my issue by disabling the "secure transfer required". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-require-secure-transfer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gaurav said, with support for **SMB 3.0**, file storage now supports encryption and persistent handles from SMB 3.0 clients. Support for encryption means that SMB 3.0 clients can mount a file share from anywhere, including from:
[image]
[image]

I had reproduce this error, I create a VM(windows 2008 SMB 2.1) in Australia East, and the storage account (file share) in East US. Because the windows 2008 R2 is SMB 2.1 and deploy in different regions:

[image]

By the way, if you want to mount the file share on the on-premises client, you have to make sure your firewall allows traffic across **port 445** AND your ISP (some ISPs do not open port 445).